# Bash array is not written properly into a variable

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, binary

I'm trying to write a simple bash script which calculates a decimal number into a binary number. Everything works well until I calculate a number greater than 255.

I had to read id from right to left for a correct result so I decided to create a function which saves the 0's and 1's into a array for each one. Then I wrote the array into a variable by starting at the highest number. Now the problem is that this works for the number 255 but for higher numbers it does something I can't understand, the result are numbers from 0-9 which logically should not be possible. Has anyone a idea why?

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

function thegreatervalue {

declare -a localArray
local -a localArray
outN=""
Gmain=$eingabe
Gmod=$eingabe
Gout="Result: "
GoutC=""

localArray[counter]=""

while [ $Gmain -ne 0 ];
do
    counter=""
    minuscounter=""

    if [ $(( $Gmod % 2 )) -eq 1 ];then
        localArray[counter]+="1"

    else
        localArray[counter]+="0"

    fi

    Gmain=$(( $Gmain / 2 ))
    Gmod=$(( $Gmod / 2 ))
    counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
    minuscounter=$(( $minuscounter + 1 ))

done

echo "in the LoAr: ${localArray[@]}"

while [ $minuscounter -ne 0 ];
do
    i=$minuscounter
    i=$(( $i - 1 ))
    minuscounter=$(( $minuscounter - 1 ))
    outN=$(( $outN + "${localArray[i]}" ))
done

while [ $(( 8 - ${#outN} )) -ne 0 ];
do
    outN+="0"
done

echo $Gout$outN

}
echo "Decimal: "
    read eingabe 

if [ $eingabe -gt 254 ];then
    thegreatervalue

else
    echo "enter a number higher than 254!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$bc <<< "obase=2;255"
11111111
$bc <<< "obase=2;256"
100000000
```

Binary for

255 --> 11111111 (8 digits)
256 --> 100000000 (9 digits)

```
while [ $(( 8 - ${#outN} )) -ne 0 ];
do
    outN+="0"
done
```

This part of your code is not working as `8 - ${#outN}` will keep on incrmenting in negative